# Find next date value in the column

Tags: sql

I have a large table with the following columns and sample values:

```
ID  Ser     Reg Date
1   12345   001 1/3/2011
1   12345   001 2/2/2011
1   12345   002 1/3/2011
1   12345   002 2/2/2011
2   23456   001 1/3/2011
2   23456   001 2/7/2011
2   23456   001 3/5/2011
```

I tried this query from a previous post SQL - Select next date query - but did not get the desired results:

```
SELECT 
    mytable.id, 
    mytable.date, 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            MIN(mytablemin.date) 
        FROM mytable AS mytablemin 
        WHERE mytablemin.date > mytable.date 
    ) AS NextDate 
FROM mytable
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
ID     Ser         Reg     curr_Date   prev_Date
1      12345       001     2/2/2011    1/3/2011
1      12345       002     2/2/2011    1/3/2011
2      23456       001     2/7/2011    1/5/2011
2      23456       001     3/5/2011    2/7/2011
```

I would appreciate any help with this task.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 0):

There was a condition missing from correlated subquery joining mytablemin copy of mytable table with mytable. Also you would eliminate records which do not have NextDate - but this might give incorrect results in case when only one record in group (Id, Ser, Reg) exists by eliminating it from result set.

```
select * from
(
    SELECT 
        mytable.id, 
        mytable.date, 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                MIN(mytablemin.date) 
            FROM mytable AS mytablemin 
            WHERE mytablemin.date > mytable.date 
              and mytablemin.id = mytable.id
              and mytablemin.Ser = mytable.Ser
              and mytablemin.Reg = mytable.Reg
        ) AS NextDate 
    FROM mytable 
) a
where a.NextDate is not null
```

And here is version using derived table with aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    mytable.id, 
    mytable.date, 
    mytablemin.minDate
FROM mytable 
  inner join
  (
    SELECT mytablemin.id,
           mytablemin.Ser,
           mytablemin.Reg,
           MIN(mytablemin.date) minDate
    FROM mytable AS mytablemin 
    group by mytablemin.id,
           mytablemin.Ser,
           mytablemin.Reg
    having MIN(mytablemin.date) is not null
  ) AS mytablemin
    on mytablemin.id = mytable.id
    and mytablemin.Ser = mytable.Ser
    and mytablemin.Reg = mytable.Reg
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using oracle database (as you have not mentioned then I can assume anything)

then you can use lead and lag function/command for this ..

```
select id,ser, reg, curr_date ,prev_date
from 
(
select id,ser, reg, ser, date curr_date
LEAD(date, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY id,ser, reg, curr_date ORDER BY date DESC NULLS LAST) prev_date,
)
where prev_date is not null;
```